# How can i set the default font for my form and all child forms it creates, without touching the main code of the c# app?

Tags: c#, winforms, dynamic, plugins, fonts

What I want to achieve is the following:
Lets say we have a basic program written in C#, whatever it does, that has some controls, shows some self made dialogs, etc and has plugin support. You can load plugins dynamically during run time and unload them again. 
How could i write a plugin that lets you pick a font and then sets that picked font as the default font for the form that loaded the plugin, all of it`s child controls (which is easy), and all dialogs it shows after the font was changed?

Ive been googling for hours and most i found was something like this:

```
Form2 win = new Form2();
win.Font = this.Font;
win.ShowDialog(this);
```

while this works of course it means touching the source code and changing it everywhere a window is shown. And a plugin obviously cant re-compile a program while it runs or find all the lines of codes where it would need to make changes or do all of the above and restart the program without losing any data.

The goal is that someone who has little knowledge of the main program can still write a Plugin that lets them choose a desired font for the program. That someone would only know how to program the plugin and how to load/unload it.

Searched material includes:

[Changing default font in Windows messes up my Win Forms buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/443478/changing-default-font-in-windows-messes-up-my-win-forms-buttons)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.drawing.systemfonts.defaultfont%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
[How to use system font settings for a Windows C# app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5901299/how-to-use-system-font-settings-for-a-windows-c-sharp-app)

Comment: winforms doesn't support doing anything without "touching the code". You're looking for WPF, which supports the concept of `Styles`, where you can apply a certain style to a certain UI element or all UI elements of a given type, even in an application-wide manner.

Comment: Are you sure? Isnt there a way to catch it when the form and it`s controls retrieve the default font from the system?

Answer (score 0):

System.Drawing.Font can be instantiated with a string indicating the FontName.

```
 Label1.Font = new Font(Label1.Font.Name, currentSize, 
            Label1.Font.Style);
```

Comment: The above code changes the font of a single control. But that is not what im looking for. Im looking for a way, basically, to change the default font that is used when you create a control or a child window without explicitly setting it`s font. The default is something like Microsoft Sans Serif 8,25 if im not mistaken. The Plugin should be able to change that default font to something else that you pick once the plugin was loaded.